# Type string[] is not assignable to type "" | T

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I want to create a dropdown menu but I have an error inside the 'value={}'.
(Type string[] is not assignable to type "" | T)
The error is in this line: `value={personName}`

```
const names = [
 ...
];
const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState<string[]>([]);

    const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent<typeof personName>) => {
        const {
            target: { value }
        } = event;
        setPersonName(
            typeof value === "string" ? value.split(",") : value
        );
    };
<FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: 300, mt: 3 }}>
   <Select
     displayEmpty
     value={personName}
     onChange={handleChange}
     input={<InputBase />}
     >
   <MenuItem disabled value="">
       <em>Placeholder</em>
   </MenuItem>
    {names.map((name) => (
     <MenuItem key={name} value={name}>
          {name}
     </MenuItem>
    ))}
  </Select>
</FormControl>
```

I tried changing the types but still same error.

Comment: What line specifically is causing the error?

Comment: value={personName}